# Convert torch model (torch.save) into matricial formulas that can be handled with basic Python

Tags: numpy, torch

Please could you tell me if it is feasible to transform a torch model (torch.save) into algebraic matrices/ equations that can be operated with numpy or basic Python, without the need to install torch and other related libraries (that occupy a lot of space)? In an afirmative case, could you please give me some hints or a link with explanations? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to do this without a lot of your own work. Basically you'd have to port most of the pytorch library to numpy, which would be a huge project. If space is an issue check if you can save some space by e.g using earlier torch versions or using only the CPU-versions of pytorch.